# How can I upload an image as context with a prompt to GPT4's api?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4, chat-gpt-4

I see there are ways of doing various image generation here:  https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/images

But I'm just trying to sent chat gpt a png file, ask "what is this?" or something like that and then get back a response.

Answer (score 1):

### It is possible...

but not in chatGPT right now based on this response in their forums:

> What you want is called “image captioning” and is not a service OpenAI currently provides in their API.
>
> You can check for other APIs, such as the Azure Describe Image API, or
> a service such as hive.ai, or host your own CLIP model.

source: https://community.openai.com/t/how-can-i-get-description-from-the-content-of-the-image/307090/2

### Use Azure Computer Vision To Describe an Image

But I did find it possible to describe images with the **Azure AI services | Computer vision** API.

1. Create a free Azure account: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free
2. Go to portal.azure.com and create your own instance of Computer Vision by searching for and clicking on Computer vision and clicking the **+ Create** button
3. Enter the details it needs(sub account, name, etc) until you finish
4. Click *Manage keys: Click here to manage keys your keys and the endpoint*
5. Save your Key 1 and Endpoint values

Now you can make the curl request like so:

```
url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/12/Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg/450px-Broadway_and_Times_Square_by_night.jpg"

image_analysis = client.analyze_image(
    url, visual_features=[VisualFeatureTypes.tags])
```

Full code example is in this replit: https://replit.com/@allenmcgehee/HonoredCarefulBackticks#main.py

Comment: Thanks. I don't think the GPT4V image upload functionality is the same as image captioning though... at least the results seem very different.